# The name "ABC..." does not exist in the current context. c# SQL Console program

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, console

I'm new at this. Im making a c# console program that reads sql database via datareader, displays a statement if any row matches the query and updates those rows via sql update query. But I can't figure out how to fix this error. here is my code. help appreciated. thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace emailsend
{
    class Program
    {
        #region Connection String
        static private SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=dbTrainning;User ID=user;Password=123");
        #endregion        

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            #region SQL Select Unsent Query
            string Sql = "SELECT * FROM People where Visits is Null;";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, connection);
            #endregion

            #region Open DB Connection
            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Open();
            } 
            #endregion
            SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            #region Try Catch Block
            try
            {             
                while (DR.Read())
                {
                    #region Fetching DB data
                    DateTime TimeStamp = (DateTime)DR["ExceptionDate"];
                    string VNumber = (string)DR["VisitNumber"];
                    Console.Write("Total Visits = " +VNumber "\n");
                    #endregion
                    DR.Close();
                }

                cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE People SET Visits = '0' WHERE VisitNumber = '" + VNumber + "'", connection);   //The name 'VNumber' does not exist in the current context
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException exception)
            {
                Console.Write(exception);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            } 
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is where using the debugger as well as understanding the key term `SCOPE` if you want to have access to a variable declared inside of `{  }` to gain access to those variables you need to declare / initialize the `variable(s)` outside of the `loop or try or if`...etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you create `VNumber` in a `while` loop and it is not visible outside. try it:

```
try
{   
    string VNumber = null;      //outside the loop
    while (DR.Read())
    {
        #region Fetching DB data
        DateTime TimeStamp = (DateTime)DR["ExceptionDate"];
        VNumber = (string)DR["VisitNumber"];
        Console.Write("Total Visits = " +VNumber "\n");
        #endregion
        DR.Close();
    }

    cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE People SET Visits = '0' WHERE VisitNumber = '" + VNumber + "'", connection);   //The name 'VNumber' does not exist in the current context
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: That solved the minor problem. I see now that the variable I was referencing was created and initialized inside the loop. It should have been initialized in beginning of class/method as a **global variable**.